# iOS directories, that are writable at Compile- and Runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm programming with a deployment target of iOS5.

Is there some **directory**, which i can put in some **static files in at compile time and write to that same directory a runtime**? 
IMHO the home directory is not writable at runtime. (sandboxing?) At the moment for my runtime writes i use `NSTemporaryDirectory()`, which is not accessible at compile time..

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You put files in your bundle, and later you can copy them to another folder. I believe (but have not tested) that you can also create a link to them if they are large and you don't want to create two files. If you do this you need to think about what happens when you update the app.

Comment: You can create a link, but you'd better be sure to make it a hard copy as soon as you start making any changes.

Comment: Thank You. Yes i planned to use links anyway, my problem was though, that the linking worked in simulator, but not on the device. Now my problem was solved by noting, that file paths are case-sensitive on the device, but not on the simulator.

Comment: Note what @Farcaller says above, its important! If you change your bundle your app will stop working (or something bad happens!)